# Xorg randomly refusing to update screen and ends up blank after restarting it

Tags: linux, video, freeze, xorg

At random intervals (and I do mean *random*), X will stop refreshing the screen---for all practical purposes and by all definitions, it's frozen solid.  Whatever it was trying to display at the instant Xorg decides to sulk ends there.  Switching to a virtual terminal works, but switching back to X ends up with either a black screen, or the frozen state.  Quitting Xorg altogether brings me back to my login prompt (agetty or Qingy) just fine, but logging back in and starting a new X session just produces a black screen.

Gets rather embarrassing whenever it freezes up while I'm <strike>watching pr0n</strike> writing particularly ugly code.

The weird part is, clicks and key presses work *fine*, and so does my cursor.  I can quit any apps I'm running to save <strike>my place in a pr0n video</strike> whatever code I'm working on, tell people I'm IM'ing that I need to restart...  Does wonders for enhancing my memory when I'm left trying to figure out how many Pidgin tabs I have, and who's the person I'm talking with on the currently active one, but wreaks havoc on my uptime stats.

At first I thought it was KMS.  I turned it off, it still happens.  Thought it might be Qingy tripping me up, so I switched back to agetty and then to XDM.  Random lock ups still happen.  Thought maybe it was X punishing me for going whole-hog with the HAL configuration, so I re-copied my xorg.conf backup.  Doesn't help.

Possibly it's a driver issue, but Googling doesn't turn up anything even remotely resembling my problem as I've stated it.  Probably not a kernel issue; gone through at least 3 point releases now.

If you're experiencing the exact same (or very similar problem), but don't have a solution: please, leave a comment.  At least I'll know Xorg isn't just tripping on me.

(Oh, and by the way, I'm using Arch Linux, with the testing repo on, using an Intel 945GM vid adapter within a Toshiba Portege.)

Comment: A couple of hours after posting this, I downgraded my copy of X's Intel video driver, just for the hell of it.  *keeps his fingers crossed*  So far, so good, though it sometimes takes up to two or three days after a reboot before the problem kicks in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it really is a video driver issue.  Haven't had the problem come up since downgrading.

Heads up to anyone experiencing the same problem.  (current version installed 2.9.1; was previously at 2.9.99.902, I believe.)